# Determinant of $e^A$.

Tags: determinant, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$. Show that $$\det e^A = e^{\text{Tr } A},$$ where $\text{Tr } A$ is the trace of the matrix $A$.

This is marked as a "starred exercise" in Analysis in Euclidean Spaces by Ken Hoffman, and I have no idea how to even get started on this question.

Comment: Use Jordan canonical form (View $A$ as a complex matrix so the characteristic polynomial splits over $\mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward to verify this for diagonal matrices over the complexes.

Consequently, it's easy to show for diagonalizable matrices over the complexes.

All of the functions involved are continuous; since the diagonalizable matrices are dense in the space of all matrices, the identity holds for all matrices over the complexes.

Finally, every real matrix is a complex matrix.